# Some feedback on the sequence $ a_n=a_{n-1}+4\phi_n $

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recursion, totient-function

This sequence is present at [OEIS A171503](https://oeis.org/A171503).

There,  Jacob Siehler explains how this sequence correspond to the number of matrices with determinant one and how this number grows as we allow to vary in the set $\{0,1,...,n\}$ of available labels. Its first few terms are:
$$3,7,15,23,39,47,71,87,111,127,...$$

There the recursion in the title is told.

Further, it is easy  to verify that the sequence also counts the number of rational numbers within the 
labels $\{0,1,...,n\}$ varies:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\{0,1\}&--& 0,\pm1/1\\
\\
\{0,1,2\}&--& 0,\pm1/1,\pm2,\pm1/2\\
\\
\{0,1,2,3\}&--& 0,\pm1/1,\pm2,\pm1/2,\\
&&\pm3,\pm1/3,\pm2/3,\pm3/2\\
\\
\{0,1,2,3,4\}&--& 0,\pm1/1,\pm2,\pm1/2,\pm3,\pm1/3,\pm2/3,\pm3/2,\\
&&\pm4,\pm1/4,\pm3/4,\pm4/3\\
\\
\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}&--& 0,\pm1/1,\pm2,\pm1/2,\pm3,\pm1/3,\pm2/3,\pm3/2,\pm4,\pm1/4,\pm3/4,\pm4/3,\\
&&\pm5,\pm1/5,\pm2/5,\pm3/5,
\pm4/5,\pm5/2,\pm5/3,\pm5/4
\end{eqnarray*}
Evindently we are using of the Eulerphi's function.

In sight of this, and with the aim of increasing the folklore,
I am asking if in ours audience (MSE) someone
else knows or had found others relations or connections with this interesant sequence.

Comment: You might also mention that $a_n = -1 + 4 \sum_{j=1}^n \phi(j)$.

Comment: Yes, to be fair :D

Comment: but also we have:  *Number of distinct solutions to $kx+h=0$, where $|h|\le n$ and $k=1,2,...,n$. - Giovanni Resta, Jan 08 2013*

Comment: upgraded: https://oeis.org/A171503